# EntityFramework Procedure or function '' expects parameter '', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I apologise for asking just a basic question, however I cannot find the cause of this error.

I am using Entity Framework to execute a Stored Procedure, and I am passing in four parameters, however the SQL Database seems to reject them. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My code:

```
ObjectResult<SearchDirectoryItem> resultList = container.ExecuteStoreQuery<SearchDirectoryItem>("SearchDirectoryEntries",
            new SqlParameter("@DirectoryId", search.DirectoryId),
            new SqlParameter("@Latitude", point.Latitude),
            new SqlParameter("@Longitude", point.Longitude),
            new SqlParameter("@Range", search.RangeMiles));
```

Which produces the error:

> Procedure or function 'SearchDirectoryEntries' expects parameter '@DirectoryId', which was not supplied.

The SQL generated is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SearchDirectoryEntries',N'@DirectoryId int,@Latitude decimal(7,5),@Longitude decimal(6,5),@Range int',@DirectoryId=3,@Latitude=53.36993,@Longitude=-2.37013,@Range=10
```

The stored procedures is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchDirectoryEntries]
@DirectoryId int,
@Latitude decimal(18, 6),
@Longitude decimal(18, 6),
@Range int
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the declaration of your SQL stored procedure?  Up to where the parameters are defined?

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchDirectoryEntries]
 @DirectoryId int,
 @Latitude decimal(18, 6),
 @Longitude decimal(18, 6),
 @Range int

Cheers

Comment: What are the definitions of the `search` and `point`? i.e. Is `search.DirectoryId` an `int`?

Comment: None of the values are null, they are all passed to SQL:

exec sp_executesql N'SearchDirectoryEntries',N'@DirectoryId int,@Latitude decimal(7,5),@Longitude decimal(6,5),@Range int',@DirectoryId=3,@Latitude=53.36993,@Longitude=-2.37013,@Range=10

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The commandText param in your query is incorrect. It should be a call to a stored procedure with parameters instead of just stored procedure name:

```
ObjectResult<SearchDirectoryItem> resultList = container.ExecuteStoreQuery<SearchDirectoryItem>(
    "Exec SearchDirectoryEntries @DirectoryId, @Latitude, @Longitude, @Range",
     new SqlParameter("DirectoryId", search.DirectoryId),
     new SqlParameter("Latitude", point.Latitude),
     new SqlParameter("Longitude", point.Longitude),
     new SqlParameter("Range", search.RangeMiles));
```

Also don't forget to remove '@' from SqlParameter constructor.

Comment: Thank you! Totally fixed my issue after numerous false starts.

Comment: Nowhere in the documentation for `SqlParameter` does it specify to remove the `@` from the name. Where is that coming from? You will have to remove it if you are using an `ObjectParameter` however.