# Error calling stored procedure from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm receiving the following error:

> Procedure or function 'dsp_DeleteAgreementPackage' expects parameter '@AgreementPackageID', which was not supplied.

Here's my code:

```
var param1 = new SqlParameter();
param1.ParameterName = "@AgreementPackageID";
param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
param1.SqlValue = package.Id;
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dsp_DeleteAgreementPackage", param1);
```

I've also tried replacing the last line with:

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dsp_DeleteAgreementPackage", new object[] { param1 });
```

I get the same error both ways. I've verified that `param1` does include the integer value and a parameter name of `@AgreementPackageID`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not including any parameter inside provided SQL command string (the parameters are required instead of simply using stored procedure name). Try using `ExecuteSqlCommand` with given `@AgreementPackageID` parameter as given below:

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dsp_DeleteAgreementPackage @AgreementPackageID", param1);
```

Also you can remove `@` sign from `ParameterName` if necessary:

```
param1.ParameterName = "AgreementPackageID";
```

Similar issues:

[EntityFramework Procedure or function '' expects parameter '', which was not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493494/entityframework-procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-was-not-sup)

[Call stored procedure using ExecuteSqlCommand (expects parameters which was not supplied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914166/call-stored-procedure-using-executesqlcommand-expects-parameters-which-was-not)